# How do I dance?

Tags: destiny-2

After beating one of the bosses and getting the loot from the chest I found one of my teammates dancing.  However, pulling up the Options > Key Mappings menu and I found no such option to toggle a dance mode.

I tried Interact, which is default mapped to <kbd>E</kbd> but that doesn't seem to do anything.

If anything, how do I dance?

Comment: do you have an emote that does a dance? the dances at least in destiny 1 were all emotes that you either found or came from Everence trading company.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no "dance" button listed specifically in the key bindings. But the arrow keys are your "emotes" as seen in the bottom right of this image.

[image: destiny 2 keybindings]

It should be the right arrow for dance, up to wave, left to point and down to sit.